# how can i get user object of logged in users in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, filter

I am trying to redirect users to specific page. It works for a single users but i also want to redirect each users to specific page based on their login information.

> How can i edit this code `$user_info = get_userdata(9100008);` to
>   get current logged in users `user_data`?.

```
add_filter('woocommerce_login_redirect', 'wc_login_redirect');

function wc_login_redirect( ) {

  $user_info = get_userdata(9100008);
  //$user_info = get_current_user_id();
  //$user_id = get_current_user_id(); 

  if ($user_id == 0) {
    $redirect_to = 'http://example.com/'.$user_info->user_login.'/';
    return $redirect_to;
  }
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With

```
global $current_user;
//example for id;
$id=$current_user->ID;
```

or

```
$data=get_currentuserinfo();
```

Snippet

```
add_filter('woocommerce_login_redirect', 'wc_login_redirect');

function wc_login_redirect($redirect_to ) {
global $current_user;
$id=$current_user->ID;

  if ($id == 0)  // this makes no sense, because this will never be true. Should probably be $id!=0
  {
    $redirect_to = 'http://example.com/'.$current_user->user_login.'/';
  }
    return $redirect_to;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Flyer, I put it like this but takes me top the home page `global $current_user;
$id=$current_user->ID;
$user_info = get_userdata($id);

if ($user_id == 0) {
    $redirect_to = 'http://example.com/'.$user_info->user_login.'/';
    return $redirect_to;
}
}`

Comment: that's because you get id into $id, but check $user_id. I've updated answer with complete code snippet.

Comment: when login I get blank screen when i refresh it it takes me to my account page i change the id to `$id == 9100010`

Comment: Now it takes me top the home page.

Comment: here how i put it  `add_filter('woocommerce_login_redirect', 'wc_login_redirect');

function wc_login_redirect($redirect_to ) {
global $current_user;

$id=$current_user->ID;
//$current_user = get_userdata($id) ;
  if ($id == 9100010)  // this makes no sense, because this will never be true. Should probably be $id!=0
  {
    $redirect_to = 'http://example.com/'.$current_user->user_login.'/';
  }
    return $redirect_to;
}

`

Comment: I assume homepage is where user is taken after log in by default. If so, your condition `$id == 9100010` simply doesn't happen. Are you sure, that ID of the user you're testing on is 9100010?

Answer (score 1):

There's a function exactly for this purpose called `get_current_user_id()` (which is commented out in your code, for some reason).

Read more [in the Codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_current_user_id).

If you need the current user OBJECT (as your code implies), you can use [`wp_get_current_user()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_current_user).

Comment: Looks like he wants the user object and not the ID. He should instead use [https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_current_user](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_current_user), that way he doesn't have to adjust any code except for `get_userdata()`

Comment: @Ohgodwhy...The question title asks specifically for the user ID...But then again, his/her code seems to contradict that later on.

Comment: @Ohgodwhy Thanks When i replace `$user_info = get_userdata(9100008);` to  `$user_info = wp_get_current_user();`  it redirect me to the home page

Comment: @rnevius Thanks! sorry about that Ohgodwhy is right, thats what am looking for. I just updated the title. Thanks